# Incorporate another dimension to non-negative matrix factorization (NMF)?

Tags: audio, source-separation, matrix-factorization

My first data profile has 3 dimensions; atom pattern (I think it is similar to frequency), time, and signal intensity. I can use supervised NMF for source separation straightforwardly. Because the atom pattern can be overlap, the first result is just acceptable.

I can retrieve the second data profile as a Boolean vector. At specific time point, some atom pattern has another underlying pattern which can be describe with a Boolean vector. Are there some good ways to incorporate another dimension of information as a boolean vector into NMF model? I try to find a similar data in audio processing, but not yet found. Any reference or idea are greatly appreciate.

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand what your ultimate goal is. Could you explain: 1. what are your *source*s? 2. why is the *first result* just acceptable and how is this related to the atom patterns overlapping? 3. how do you *retrieve the second data profile*? 4. what is the *second data profile*? 5. how are the *atom pattern*s related to *another underlying pattern that can be described with a Boolean vector*?

Comment: In addition to my previous comment: Can you formulate a *cost function* that you want to minimize? If so, it is probably much easier for people to help as the complete optimization problem is described by the cost function.

Comment: @applesoup I fixed as you suggested and posted here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54578/using-complex-number-in-non-negative-matrix-factorization-nmf-for-signal-sourc . I would be very appreciate if you may take a look. Thank you very much.